# unable to convert yaml string to json string using java

Tags: java, json, rest, yaml

I want to convert a `yaml` string to a `json` string by using "jyaml", kindly some one help me to resolve this

YAML string :-

```
Korea:   www.gozoculture.com:     default: jhfjfjfj  www.5plus5.gov.mt:     default: jhfjfjfj  www.ces.gov.mt:     default: cesDefault    user5: chennal5  isp:     Tata DoCoMo: chennalisp1    Hathway: chennalIsp    Hong Kong: chennalisp2    Aircel: chennalIspaircel    Airtel: chennalIspAirtel  studiodefault: KoreaStudioDefault  www.wwe.com:     default: wweDefault    user2: chennal2    user1: chennal1  country:     FR: francecountryChennal    HK: HongkongCountryChennal    IN: IndaiChennal    DE: GermanyCountryChennal
```

my expected output:-

```
{
  "Singapoor": {
    "studiodefault": "chennal default singapoor site", 
    "www.gozoculture.com": {
      "default": "chennalDefault1", 
      "user1": "ch1,ch2,ch3"
    }, 
    "country": {
      "FR": "franceChennal", 
      "DE": "GermanyChennal", 
      "IN": "indiaChennal"
    }, 
    "www.justice.gov.mt": {
      "default": "justiceDefault"
    }, 
    "www.wwe.com": {
      "default": "wwechennalDefault", 
      "user2": "ch4,ch5,ch6"
    }, 
    "isp": {
      "Vodafone  Broadband": "vodafoneChennal2", 
      "Idea cellular": "ideaChennal", 
      "Airtel": "aritelChennal1"
    }, 
    "www.enemalta.com": {
      "default": "chennalDefault2", 
      "user3": "ch7,ch8,ch9"
    }
  }
}
```

java code:-

```
private static String convertToJson(String yamlString) {
    Yaml yaml= new Yaml();
    Map<String,Object> map= (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(yamlString);

    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(map);
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

output I am getting :-

```
"Korea":   "www.gozoculture.com:     default: jhfjfjfj  www.5plus5.gov.mt:     default: jhfjfjfj  www.ces.gov.mt:     default: cesDefault    user5: chennal5  isp:     Tata DoCoMo: chennalisp1    Hathway: chennalIsp    Hong Kong: chennalisp2    Aircel: chennalIspaircel    Airtel: chennalIspAirtel  studiodefault: KoreaStudioDefault  www.wwe.com:     default: wweDefault    user2: chennal2    user1: chennal1  country:     FR: francecountryChennal    HK: HongkongCountryChennal    IN: IndaiChennal    DE: GermanyCountryChennal"
```

my alternative yaml input file:-

```
Singapoor: 
  www.gozoculture.com: 
    default: chennalDefault1
    user1: ch1,ch2,ch3
  isp: 
    Airtel: aritelChennal1
    Vodafone  Broadband: vodafoneChennal2
    Idea cellular: ideaChennal
  www.enemalta.com: 
    default: chennalDefault2
    user3: ch7,ch8,ch9
  www.justice.gov.mt: 
    default: justiceDefault
  studiodefault: chennal default singapoor site
  www.wwe.com: 
    default: wwechennalDefault
    user2: ch4,ch5,ch6
  country: 
    FR: franceChennal
    IN: indiaChennal
    DE: GermanyChennal
```

when I trying to upload single key with multiple values like "user2: ch4,ch5,ch6". for this case my code does not work. I am getting this exception
:

```
Jun 18, 2015 5:29:23 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 4: Unterminated inline value
```

Comment: You should put the code and error message/issue that you are getting. That is a good practice to follow while asking question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your input is missing some linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks. But your input is not YAML. So what do you expect?

Comment: Where are the multiple values in the string scalar value "ch4,ch5,ch6"? That is a singel string value for key "user2".  Do you want to make that a sequence? Then you should put `[ch4, ch5, ch6]`

Comment: it is yaml structure only.it may consist nested objects or arrays.objects also can have multiple key value pairs.and one key can have multiple values like  user2: "ch4,ch5,ch6".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is crucial for yaml files. If your yaml file as same as in the question, the output is totally correct. In order to achieve expected json, first you  must fix your yaml file.

In order to get your expected json output your yaml file should look like this.

```
Singapoor: 
    studiodefault: "chennal default singapoor site"
    www.gozoculture.com: 
      default: "chennalDefault1"
      user1: "ch1,ch2,ch3"
    country: 
      FR: "franceChennal"
      DE: "GermanyChennal"
      IN: "indiaChennal"
    www.justice.gov.mt: 
      default: "justiceDefault"
    www.wwe.com: 
      default: "wwechennalDefault"
      user2: "ch4,ch5,ch6"
    isp: 
      Vodafone  Broadband: "vodafoneChennal2"
      Idea cellular: "ideaChennal"
      Airtel: "aritelChennal1"
    www.enemalta.com: 
      default: "chennalDefault2"
      user3: "ch7,ch8,ch9"
```

Answer (score 1):

get snakeyaml jar 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsnakeyaml15sourcesjar.htm
it may be work for you.it is work for me.